# install oci8_11g extension in opensuse

Tags: php, oracle11g, opensuse, suse, oci8

I am using Oracle-11g as database server and suse 11 64bits server as an application server. I want to enable oci8 and oci8_11g extension in PHP so can any one tell me the steps for this

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [Install oracle and php oracle extension(OCI8) in Opensuse environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960650/install-oracle-and-php-oracle-extensionoci8-in-opensuse-environment)

You need to install the following packages:

> php5-devel
>   libxml2-devel
>   zlib-devel
>   readline-devel
>   oracle-instantclient11.2-basic
>   oracle-instantclient11.2-devel

And compile [oci8 php extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8)

A [howto](https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/installing-oracle-php-extensions-suse-linux/) from suse website

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/360835/suse-12-1-apache-startup-after-oci8-installation) also can help you