# Install oracle and php oracle extension(OCI8) in Opensuse environment

Tags: php, oracle, opensuse, oci8

I am using oracle database server Now I want to install oracle in Opensuse environment.It completelty work in ubuntu and Windows.So please tell me steps to install php,oci8 extension and oracle in Opensuse. This is urgent.

Thank you.

Comment: If it's urgent perhaps you should contact Oracle or perhaps SuSE and have a contractor do this for you. StackOverflow is a site of people volunteering their time and knowledge to help others who are trying to help themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the following packages:

> php5-devel
>   libxml2-devel
>   zlib-devel
>   readline-devel
>   oracle-instantclient11.2-basic
>   oracle-instantclient11.2-devel

And compile [oci8 php extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8)

A [howto](https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/installing-oracle-php-extensions-suse-linux/) from suse website

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/360835/suse-12-1-apache-startup-after-oci8-installation) also can help you